# How are these two statements logically equivalent?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I am confused as to how the following two statements are logically equivalent:

$\forall a > 0, \,y < a $ _____(1)

and

$\forall a > 0, \,y \leq a $ _____(2)

Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I understand,

(1) $\iff$ y $\leq 0$

And,

(2) $\iff$  y $\leq 0$ or y = a.

Could somebody help me understand how (1) $\iff$  (2)?

Thanks!

Comment: Case 1: $y=a$.  Case 2: $y\neq a$.

Comment: Remember that $y\leq a$ should be true **for all** $a>0$, and if it happens to be true for a specific value of $a$, lets call it $a_1$ then it should also be true for a value half that size, $\frac{1}{2}a_1$.  Do you see why it doesn't make a difference then whether we used a $<$ or a $\leq$?

Comment: You second equivalence "(2) $\Leftrightarrow y\leq0$ or $y=a$" doesn't make sense since the variable $a$ is bound in the left statement (by $\forall$) but free in the right statement.

Comment: Since $y \ne a$ for all possible $a$ then: $y\le 0$ or $y=a$ for all $a$ $\iff$ $y \le 0$.

Comment: They are not **logically** equivalent; in the universe of **integers**, if $y=1,$ then (1) is false but (2) is true. They **are** equivalent in the universe of **real numbers**. Suppose (2) holds; so $y\le a$ holds for every positive real number $a.$ If $a$ is a positive real number, then $a/2$ is also a positive real number, so it follows from (2) that $y\le a/2\lt a.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wholly depends on the domain of discourse.

The statements are equivalent *in the domain of real numbers* (or the rationals or similar), because such a domain has no minimum positive value.

1. $\forall a{\in}\Bbb R~(a>0\to y<a)$

   - The constant $y$ is strictly less than *any* positive value
   - The constant $y$ is non-positive.
2. $\forall a{\in}\Bbb R~(a>0\to y\leqslant a)$

   - The constant $y$ is strictly not-greater than *any* positive value.
   - The constant $y$ is non-positive.

We can see that if $y$ is non-positive, both statements clearly hold true.   Now consider that if there were any positive real value equal to $y$ (that is, if $y$ were a positive real value) then there would exist a positive real values less than it; for example: $y/2$.   This would falsify both statements.

So for any real number $y$, both statements will have *the same truth value*.

---

However this is not true of some other domains: for example, the integers, where there is *a minimum positive value*.   For the integers, that is $1$.   Witness: $\forall a{\in}\Bbb Z~(a>0\to 1<a)$ is clearly not equivalent to $\forall a{\in}\Bbb Z ~(a>0\to 1\leq a)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say $y=a$ is a possibility for (2) because you are quantifying over all possible $a$, so there's no specific $a$ for $y$ to equal.

The two statements aren't logically equivalent (some mathematical properties are required to show any equivalence), but they are both equivalent to $y \leq 0$ if you are quantifying over real numbers. To see why, suppose $y>0$. Clearly (1) cannot hold. For (2), take $a=\frac{y}{2}$.